# Error when I type in the command bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

Whenever I try to type the command:

`bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

It comes up with this error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': /home/nathan/Rails_Projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:19
```

Comment: It would be good if you could show the code in the file since it seems    from the error message that you have missed to add an end somewhere.

Comment: You look like a kid. Are you really one. If so I appreciate your interest in technology at this age :)

Comment: This is the copy of static_pages_spec.rb http://pastebin.com/RJvJQd22

Comment: Well Line 12 should be `it "should have the title 'Home'" do` instead of `it "should have the title 'Home'"` . You missing the `do` there

Answer (score 0):

Your test file, `static_pages_spec.rb`, has too many `end`s in it, or an error earlier on that means it's missing the opening construct for a valid `end`.

The parser is encountering `kEND` (that is, "keyword end") instead of `$end` (that is, the end of the file).

EDIT: It looks like you're missing a `do` on line 12 of your paste (and you indentation for lines 7-14 is out of whack).

Comment: This is the copy of static_pages_spec.rb pastebin.com/RJvJQd22

Comment: @NathanDunn - I'll have a look in half an hour; irritatingly, work block access to pastebin except during lunch hour.

Comment: @NathanDunn - Had a look, looks like line 12 is to blame.